# Where can I put helper functions for my theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I wrote few helper functions and now I want to add these functions somewhere, so that I can call them from any template files.

Where should I put them?

Comment: You should avoid using any helper function in template files.

Comment: Why?? Can you please explain it

Comment: Putting logics in views layer is a very bad design. If you want to have some dynamic value. You should do it in preprocess function at template.php and pass the value through $variables array to those template files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helper functions is a bit vague for a description (so there may be better places where to put this, like a custom module), but theme functions are usually put into the `template.php` file of your theme.

It is not generally adviced to put much php code into your templates however (save for printing variables) - best practice usually calls for the use of alter hooks or other preprocess functions. Get a (small) overview here: [template.php](https://www.drupal.org/node/1728096)

Comment: Can I also preprocess a region ?

Comment: Indeed you can. The hook you would want to use is template_preprocess_region(&$variables) - check out the documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_region/7.x